# upload image from wordpress default text editor

Tags: wordpress

Now I am trying to insert an image into my post as a customer, While the default text editor can not upload images.It only uses image url to insert an image to a post.

After a long time searching wp plugins I failed ):

How can I insert an image file into a post?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default editor can upload images. Does it work as an admin? If so you need to up your user-roll to give it more rights. It should be author or higher.

More information look for `upload_files`
http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Capability_vs._Role_Table

Comment: It works as subscriber. Is there any way to upload image as subscriber? thanks.

Comment: you could use a plugin like: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/capsman/ But I'd advise to just upgrade the current user roll.